# Force HTTPS using Redirect in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https, mod-alias

I've recently tried to force HTTPS on my website by using various directives contained in `mod_rewrite`. However it didn't workout very well and now it's recommented to use the `Redirect` directive from `mod_alias`. I've got everything in a subfolder and I wrote:

```
Redirect "/folder/" "https://mywebsite.org/folder/"
```

in my .htaccess file, but it keeps giving me the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

Answer (score 1):

This code in .htaccess will redirect http://example.com to https://example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: May be you enabled redirect from hosting admin panel? Which hosting are you using?